# Perform custom action after ng-repeat is completed rendering elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to make a manipulation with DIV element that is a result of ng-repeat:

```
   <div ng-repeat="data in info" >
       <div id='plot_{{data.id}}'></div>   
   </div>
```

My sequence is as follows:

1. I add information in $scope.info
2. ng-repeat happens
3. after DIV is generated (as you can see, it has also the dynamically assigned ID), I need to call a particular routine to insert a plot into that DIV.

How I can code the step 3 to happen right after ng-repeat rendering happens?

Comment: You need to create directive for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a directive to go on your generated div, and insert your plot within the directive.

```
app.directive('plot', function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    //Insert plot here
    //Maybe something like: $.plot(element, yourData);
    console.log('directive ' + scope.data.id + ' done');
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in info" >
   <div id='plot_{{data.id}}' plot></div>   
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0HJnXFnnfasC76K944M?p=preview)

Comment: This works with `ng-repeat` because of a little known property of a directive called `priority`.  `Priority` determines when in the digest cycle, the directive is compiled. `Ng-repaet` has a `priority` of 1000, meaning that it gets compiled before anything else.  When dealing with other directives, I usually set my `priority` to below zero to make sure that it's the last thing that happens.  Especially if it's DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Jerrad, that works technically, so I have directive code called. But when I do inside directive         
        var divElem = document.getElementById(divName); where divName is "id" in my code snippet, then I get null. Why is that?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov, because the id of the element hasn't been bound yet when the directive function executes.  Wrap your `gelElementById` in a `$timeout` to make it wait to run until after the `$digest` cycle.  I've updated the demo link in my answer to show this.